# Complicated pandas merge operation

Tags: python, join, merge, pandas

I am still quite new to joining/merging data in Pandas, so would therefore very much appreciate any help to do the following operation. I have the following three SQL tables (converted to DataFrames) of data:

`df1

Out[14]:

----       fruit  price  qty

2010   apple     1.0  2.0

2011   apple    3.0  4.0

2010  banana    0.5  1.5

2011  banana    7.0  8.0`

`df2

Out[15]:

 ----      fruit  weight

2010   apple      10

2010  banana      12`

`df3

Out[16]:

--    fruit  colour

0   apple     red

1  banana  yellow`

Where df2 has the same fruits as df1, but not the same years (I'm almost completely sure that df2's years are a subset of df1, although it would be nice to find a method, that allows for years in df2 that aren't included in df1). Df3 is a table with characters for all the fruits contained in df2 and df1. I would like to merge the three tables together, so each row in the new combined DataFrame has year, fruit, price, qty, weight (possibly NaN) and colour. I am not sure if such a data structure would be best contained in a Panel or a DataFrame - inputs on this are also very welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ensure there isn't an issue with the years, I would first reset_index:

```
In [11]: df1.index.name = 'year'

In [12]: df2.index.name = 'year'

In [13]: df1.reset_index(inplace=True)

In [14]: df2.reset_index(inplace=True)

In [15]: df1
Out[15]: 
   year   fruit  price  qty
0  2010   apple    1.0  2.0
1  2011   apple    3.0  4.0
2  2010  banana    0.5  1.5
3  2011  banana    7.0  8.0

[4 rows x 4 columns]

In [16]: df2
Out[16]: 
   year   fruit  weight
0  2010   apple      10
1  2010  banana      12

[2 rows x 3 columns]
```

Now you can get your result by merging (twice):

```
In [17]: df1.merge(df2, how='left').merge(df3, how='left')
Out[17]: 
   year   fruit  price  qty  weight  colour
0  2010   apple    1.0  2.0      10     red
1  2011   apple    3.0  4.0     NaN     red
2  2010  banana    0.5  1.5      12  yellow
3  2011  banana    7.0  8.0     NaN  yellow

[4 rows x 6 columns]
```

If you were confident that there was only one weight of fruit (i.e. independent of the year) you could just drop the year column from df2:

```
In [18]: del df2['year']

In [19]: df1.merge(df2, how='left').merge(df3, how='left')
Out[19]: 
   year   fruit  price  qty  weight  colour
0  2010   apple    1.0  2.0      10     red
1  2011   apple    3.0  4.0      10     red
2  2010  banana    0.5  1.5      12  yellow
3  2011  banana    7.0  8.0      12  yellow

[4 rows x 6 columns]
```

*Otherwise you could do a groupby and ffill.*

Answer (score 0):

At first all JOIN may be performed in SQL - and it will be faster.

If you still want do it only in python use [pandas.join](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging):

```
import pandas as pd
df_1_2_joined = pd.join(df1,df2, on='fruit', how='inner')
joined = pd.join(df_1_2_joined,df3, on='fruit', how='inner')
```

OR

```
joined = df1.join(df2, on='fruit').join(df3, on='fruit')
```

parameter how here is full analogue of SQL-JOINs types INNER|OUTER|LEFT|RIGHT

Comment: Hm, I can't get your first (or second) suggestion to work. Isn't the syntax for join, df.join(..)?